# image multi classification with keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, multilabel-classification

so if I have two labels "dogs" and "cats" and I want to create multi classification neural network.

now if I provided a new random image which is not a dog or a cat, is there a way I can teach the classifier to tell me that this image is not a dog or a cat instead of saying how much percent it maybe cat or dog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to **create a new class** in addition to dog and cat to handle images you have no interest in. So now, your labels would be `["dogs", "cats", "other"]`.

In your current architecture, your model is forced to predict a random image as either a dog or cat as those are the only two options it has. Adding a new class to deal with other images is generally the easiest way to make your classifier more robust to incorrect predictions.

Comment: but should I add some random examples in this "other" class or not ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add some random images.